# Jackson polymorphic deserialization using annotations

Tags: java, jackson, deserialization, jackson2, jackson-databind

Assume we have the following types:

```
interface Animal {}
class Dog implements Animal {...}
class Cat implements Animal {...}
class Zoo {
    private String animalType;
    private Animal animal;
    ...
}
```

Having that `Cat` and `Dog` have different properties, how can we deserialize `Zoo` object to appropriate Animal subtype based on `animalType` string which is always present in json ? I know how to do that with `custom deserialization` but i can't find the way to do the same using `Jackson annotations`. This would be possible if `animalType` property resides in `Cat` or `Dog` but in my case its location is in `Zoo`.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can annotate the `animal` field in `Zoo` with `JsonTypeInfo` to specify which subtype you want `Dog` or `Cat` per the `animalType` field also in `Zoo`. The tricky bit is to specify that the specific type of `Animal` will come from a property outside of `Animal` in the JSON i.e. an `EXTERNAL_PROPERTY`

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY, property = "animalType")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat"),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog")
})
private Animal animal;
```

Comment: Thank you , the JsonTypeInfo.As.EXTERNAL_PROPERTY is exactly what i was looking for .